# What is the best way to use Factory Pattern?

Tags: java, factory-pattern

I have a factory in my Java appplication. it looks like:

```
// Common Interface
 interface Currency {
   String getSymbol();
  }

// Concrete Rupee Class code
class Rupee implements Currency {
       @Override
       public String getSymbol() {
              return "Rs";
       }
}

// Concrete SGD class Code
class SGDDollar implements Currency {
       @Override
       public String getSymbol() {
              return "SGD";
       }
}


// Concrete US Dollar code
class USDollar implements Currency {
       @Override
       public String getSymbol() {
              return "USD";
       }
}
```

And I have a FactoryClass:

```
class CurrencyFactory {

       public static Currency createCurrency (String country) {
       if (country. equalsIgnoreCase ("India")){
              return new Rupee();
       }else if(country. equalsIgnoreCase ("Singapore")){
              return new SGDDollar();
       }else if(country. equalsIgnoreCase ("US")){
              return new USDollar();
        }
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such currency");
       }
}
```

So if a country String, for example, is "India" it returns rupees. I need to implement that if a country String is "all" it returns all objects as rupees, sgddollars and us dollars. Is any example of such thing?

Comment: I've no idea what you're asking here. Do you want to return a *list* of currencies in case of 'all'?

Comment: Incase of "all" you want to return an array or list? because a Currency object can be the of only one type at a time.

Comment: Yes. is it possible with Factory pattern?

Comment: So I just need to return list in all the times? But in case of "India" it will be only one item in the list, and in case of "all" it will be 3?

Comment: I think some rethinking has to be made regarding the design approach here.

Comment: @user1788867: you either have to create another method handling 'all' currencies or you need to introduce an abstraction... just create a method like `getAllCurrencies`

Comment: Furthermore, I agree with @silverback. It does not make any sense to maintain one class per currency. You might want to have a look at the design of java.util.Currency: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like this

Create a Class as AllCurrency

```
 public class AllCurrency implements Currency{

private Rupee rupee;
private SGDDollar sgdDollar;
private USDollar useDoler;

public AllCurrency (Rupee rupee,SGDDollar sgDoler,USDollar usDoller){
    this.rupee = rupee;
    this.sgdDollar = sgDoler;
    this.usDoller = usDoller
}

@Override
   public String getSymbol() {
          return "all";
   }

// add getters and setters
```

}

And your factory

```
public static Currency createCurrency (String country) {
   if (country. equalsIgnoreCase ("India")){
          return new Rupee();
   }else if(country. equalsIgnoreCase ("Singapore")){
          return new SGDDollar();
   }else if(country. equalsIgnoreCase ("US")){
          return new USDollar();
    }else if(country. equalsIgnoreCase ("all")){
          return new AllCurency(new Rupee(),new SGDDollar(),new USDollar());
    }
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such currency");
   }
```

Comment: Hm, this would require a downcast at the caller, e.g. `((AllCurrency)c).rupee`

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use a `Map` to look it up? You **don't have to** use patterns just to be fancy. In certain situations they will just make your code messy.

Comment: +1 for 'you don't have to use patterns just to be fancy'!